# WCF Message Intersecpter Configuration Problems

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap, idispatchmessageinspector

This question appears to have been asked multiple times, but I just can't get it to work.

Firstly, I have now tried this on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 using VS 2012 on both and have exactly the same problem.

I am trying to write a WCF service that receives and processes a SOAP header message and after a lot of searching have found that I should be using a Message Interceptor to read and process the SOAP header.

So I have created a new web site on my local machine and called it DemoMessageInspector. Within this solution I have added the following classes:

**HmacVerificationBehavior**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description

Public Class HmacVerificationBehavior
    Implements IEndpointBehavior
  #Region "IEndpointBehavior Members"

Public Sub AddBindingParameters(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, bindingParameters As System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters

End Sub

Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior

End Sub

Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, endpointDispatcher As System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
    Dim inspector As New HmacVerificationInspector()

    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector)
End Sub

Public Sub Validate(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate

End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

**HmacVerificationConfigurationSection**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Configuration
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description

Namespace NamespaceHere

Public Class HmacVerificationConfigurationSection
    Inherits BehaviorExtensionElement
    Implements IServiceBehavior

#Region "IServiceBehavior Members"

    Public Sub AddBindingParameters(serviceDescription As ServiceDescription, serviceHostBase As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase, endpoints As System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ServiceEndpoint), bindingParameters As System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection) Implements IServiceBehavior.AddBindingParameters

    End Sub

    Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(serviceDescription As ServiceDescription, serviceHostBase As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase) Implements IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior

    End Sub

    Public Sub Validate(serviceDescription As ServiceDescription, serviceHostBase As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase) Implements IServiceBehavior.Validate

    End Sub

#End Region

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property BehaviorType() As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(HmacVerificationBehavior)
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function CreateBehavior() As Object
        Return New HmacVerificationBehavior()
    End Function

End Class

End Namespace
```

**HmacVerificationInspector**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher
Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels

Public Class HmacVerificationInspector
Implements IDispatchMessageInspector


#Region "IDispatchMessageInspector Members"

Public Function AfterReceiveRequest(ByRef request As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, channel As System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel, instanceContext As System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext) As Object
    Dim buffer As MessageBuffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue)
    request = buffer.CreateMessage()
    Dim dupeRequest As Message = buffer.CreateMessage()

    ValidateHmac(dupeRequest)

    buffer.Close()

    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Sub BeforeSendReply(ByRef reply As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, correlationState As Object)


End Sub

#End Region

Public Function AfterReceiveRequest1(ByRef request As Message, channel As ServiceModel.IClientChannel, instanceContext As ServiceModel.InstanceContext) As Object Implements IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest

End Function

Public Sub BeforeSendReply1(ByRef reply As Message, correlationState As Object) Implements IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply

End Sub
End Class
```

**IService**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel

' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the interface name "IService" in both code and config file together.'
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService

<OperationContract()>
Sub DoWork()

<OperationContract()>
Function DoSomething(ByVal _str As String) As String


End Interface
```

**And Service**

```
Public Class Service
Implements IService

Public Sub DoWork() Implements IService.DoWork
End Sub

Public Function DoSomething(ByVal _str As String) As String Implements IService.DoSomething

    Return "Message [" & _str & "]"

End Function

End
```

The Web.Config file is as follows:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="hmacVerification" 
         type="NamespaceHere.HmacVerificationConfigurationSection, NamespaceHere, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
     </behaviorExtensions>
   </extensions>
  <services>
    <service name="MySecureService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMySecureService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      <hmacVerification />      *********COMMENT OUT**************
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So, we have the example code which works perfectly if the  line is commented out in the Web.Config. As soon as it is uncommented the following happens:

```
Server Error in '/DemoMessageInspector' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: The type 'NamespaceHere.HmacVerificationConfigurationSection, NamespaceHere, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' registered for extension 'hmacVerification' could not be loaded.

Source Error: 



Line 25:         <behavior name="web">
Line 26:           <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
Line 27:           <hmacVerification />
Line 28:         </behavior>
Line 29:       </endpointBehaviors>


 Source File:  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoMessageInspector\web.config    Line:  27 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044
```

So, the question is basically how should this be configured?

Or maybe the question is, Is this the right approach to use to complete a simple task as reading a SOAP header from a WCF endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is “complete a simple task as reading a SOAP header from a WCF endpoint”, then you should be able to use:

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders
```

The following link contains implementation details for the IncomingMessageHeaders collection:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.incomingmessageheaders.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the link provided.